# Sharing one propagation constant in circular waveguide

Tags: waveguide

I need to know more about this sentence for circular wave-guide structure:

"When mode degeneration occurs, two modes sharing one propagation constant may be linearly combined. There are two possibilities to define the polarization of degenerated modes."

1. what does "sharing one propagation constant" mean?
2. why do two different polarization possibilities exist? Not many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always possible to be certain one understands what is meant by a description like this without being able to ask the person that wrote it. However, I'll try to clarify as I understand it.

1. The phrase "sharing one propagation constant" is more or less what the degenerate means. When two modes in a wave guide are *degenerate* then they have the same propagation constant. Since they have the same propagation constant, any linear combination of the two mode would again be a mode of the wave guide. As a result degenerate modes are not unique.
2. I think what the description means is that there are always two orthogonal states of polarization in terms of which all other states of polarization can be expressed as linear combinations. If the two degenerate modes in a wave guide have linearly independent states of polarization then one can use them to find a mutually orthogonal pair in terms of which one can then represent any other state of polarization.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help. 1)Gama=Propagation constant=alpha+jBeta ,(Alpha=attenuation, beta=phase constant) it means alpha and beta for both modes are the same? Because as I know the degenerate modes have same frequency not same Propagation constant. 2) does it mean we can assume (two degenerate modes) or a combination of two modes as a single mode exist in the waveguide?

Comment: it is based on "http://www.mweda.com/cst/cst2013/mergedProjects/CST_PARTICLE_STUDIO/special_overview/special_overview_waveguideover.htm" section "Mode Polarization"

Comment: In the context of waveguides, the term degenerate usually refers to the propagation constant, because the different modes can have the same frequency anyway. Yes, the superposition of two degenerate modes acts like a single mode of the waveguide.